# How to get Disk space(Avail) using 'df -h' when Filesystem is long

Tags: awk

I am trying to find available disk space through console

I found `df -h | awk '$NF == "/" { print $4 }'` to get required output.

```
[root@tmpe2etstmsdc01 ~]# df -h
Filesystem                                                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_root-lv_root                                542G   22G  492G   5% /
tmpfs                                                      127G     0  127G   0% /dev/shm
```

> Avail

```
[root@tmpe2etstmsdc01 ~]# df -h | awk '$NF == "/" { print $4 }'
492G
```

This gives `Use%` value when `Filesystem` is long

```
[root@ldrnr-tlsmsdc16 ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_root-lv_root
                   16G   16G     0 100% /
tmpfs             1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
```

Here, the command gives `Use%` instead of `Avail`

```
[root@ldrnr-tlsmsdc16 ~]# df -h | awk '$NF == "/" { print $4 }'
100%
```

How can i get `Avail` in this condition?

Comment: This is a duplicate of a function. I know I answered something similar yesterday, or the day before yesterday. Look it the monit package, it is more standard then rolling out your own scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df -h | awk '$NF == "/" { if($1 ~ /^[0-9]/) print $3; else print $4 }'
```

or

```
df -h | awk '$NF == "/" { if($5 == "/") print $3; else print $4 }'
```

Comment: or just `{print $(NF-2)}`

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
stat -fc %a /mountpoint
```

`%a` is available blocks for non-superuser.  Use `%f` for total free blocks.  Note also that `%s` is blocksize, so if you want, say, total free bytes you could say something like:

```
stat -fc '%f * %s' /mountpoint | bc
```

See the [stat(1) man page for more options](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html). In general `stat(1)` will be easier to work with than `df` for parseable output.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU coreutils, you can use this:

```
df -h --output=avail / | sed '1d'
```

To print only the `Avail` row of the filesystem mounted on `/`. Unfortunatly `df` has no option to disable the header line, so `sed` removes the first line.

Comment: `df --output` is not available in GNU coreutils 8.4

Answer (score 0):

You can try with awk also:

```
df -h|tail -n +2 | awk '{if ($5 == "/")print $3; }'
```

OR:

```
df -h|tail -n +2 | awk '{if ($6 == "/") print $4; }'
```

Depending on your df output